# Designing a data warehouse for inventory management

Tags: data-warehouse, olap-cube, star-schema

I have a college assignment requirement to built a Data warehouse for product Inventory management which can help inventory management understand in-hand value and using historical data they can predict when to bring new inventory. I have been reading to find out best way to do it using Cubes or Data mart. My question here is do I have to create a Data warehouse first and on top of that built Cube, Data mart or I can directly extract transactional data into Cube/Data Mart.

Next, Is it mandatory to built a Star Schema(or other DW schema) for doing this assignment as after reading multiple articles my understanding is OLAP cube can have multiple facts surrounded by Dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is far bigger than you know!

As a general principle, you would have a staging database(s) which lands the data from one or more OLTP systems. then the staging database(s) would feed data to a datawarehouse (DWH). On top of a DWH would be built a number of Marts, these typically are subject area specific.

There are several DWH methodologies

- [Kimball Star Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) - you mention star schema above, this broadly is Kimball Star Schema. Proposed by Ralph Kimball. Also I would include here Snowflake Schemas, which are a variation on Star Schemas.
- Inmon Model - Proposed by [Bill Inmon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Inmon)
- [Data Vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_vault_modeling) - proposed by Dan Linstedt. Has a large user base in the Benelux countries. There are variations on the Data Vault.

It's important not to get confused between a DWH methodology and the technology to implement a DWH, though sometimes there are some technologies that lend themselves to particular methodologies. For example OLAP cubes work easily with Kimball star schemas. There is no particular need to use a relational technology for particular databases. Some NoSQL databases (like Cassandra) lend themselves to staging databases well.

To answer your specific questions

> Do I have to create a Data warehouse first and on
>   top of that built Cube, Data mart or I can directly extract
>   transactional data into Cube/Data Mart.

OLAP Cubes are optional if you have a specific Mart that is tailored to your reporting but it depends on your reporting and analysis requirements and the speed of access.
A Data Mart could actually be built only using an OLAP cube, coming straight from the DWH.

Specifically on inventory management, all of these DWH methodologies would be suitable.

I can't answer your last question, as that seems to be the point of the assignment and you havn't given enough information to answer the question, but you need to do some research into [dimensional modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_modeling), so I hope this has pointed you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, a star model will always help a better analysis, but it is relational, a cube is multidimensional (where it performs all data crossings) and often uses as a data source to star models (recommended).

OLAP cubes are generally used for fast analysis and summaries of data.

So, by standard, I recommend you make all the star models you need and then generate the OLAP cubes for your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

AS this is a 'homework' question, I would guess that the lecturer is looking for pros/cons between Kimball and Inmon which are the two 'default' designs for end-user reporting.  In the real world DataVault can also be applied as part of the DWH strategy but it plays a different purpose and is not recommended for end-user consumption.

DataVault is a design pattern to bring data in from source systems unmolested.  Data will inevitably need to be cleaned before being presented to the end-user solution and DV allows the DWH ETL process to be re-run if any issues are found or the business requirements change, especially if the granularity level goes down (e.g. the original fact table was for sales and the dimension requirements were for salesman and product category, now they want fact-sales by sales round and salesman for product subcategory and category.  Without DV you do not have the granular data to replay the historical information and rebuild the DWH)